# How to run a bash script file in chef?

Tags: bash, file, chef-infra

I wrote a short bash script and stored it in `files/default/bash.sh`.

How do I link it to get it to run in my main default recipe?  It needs to run as sudo because I'm on an ubuntu system.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why this question was voted down. I had the same question and found this useful.

Answer (score 20):

After searching high and low I finally found an answer:

```
cookbook_file "/tmp/lib-installer.sh" do
  source "lib-installer.sh"
  mode 0755
end

execute "install my lib" do
  command "sh /tmp/lib-installer.sh"
end
```

Thanks to this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-extend-scripts.html)!

Comment: How to get the output or `echo` from `lib-installer.sh` to chef logs ?

Comment: I presume that lib-installer.sh should be in files/default (your OP uses bash.sh not lib-installer.sh)

Answer (score 3):

You can also include the script directly in your recipe if it isn't too long via the [`bash` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_bash.html). By default any program run by Chef uses the same user as Chef is running as, which is usually root already. You can use the `user` parameter to things like `execute` and `bash` to switch to a different user or just explicitly state that it should be root to make things self-documenting a tad.